# How can I nest my data frame based on identical values in a column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with some identical names in it, and wish to get some basic stats on some associated numbers. Originally, the data look like this:

```
name res1 res2 res3
foo   1.1   NA   10
foo   2.4   NA  2.1
foo   NA     1  1.2
bar     1    2    3
```

In order to get stats, I was thinking of nesting the data like this:

```
name       res1  res2           res3
foo   [1.1,2.4]   [1]   [10,2.1,1.2]
bar         [1]   [2]            [3]
```

This would be a step doing things like getting the mean and S.D, etc. of each vector. i.e. I would then add columns for the mean of res1, the SD of res1, etc. How can I nest my data frame based on identical values in a column?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with nesting as such, I'd just make a "long" dataset instead, something like `cbind(dat["name"], stack(dat[-1]))` where you have 3 columns - `name`/`group`/`values`/. If you have summary-level stats (mean/sd etc), they should be stored at a summary level in a separate dataset.

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail, that sounds interesting. If you could post up some code for how to proceed with the stats part, that would be most useful! Cheers.

Comment: I worked out a strategy based on your suggestion, @thelatemail. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am agree with thelatemail's suggestion, you can get desired output with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dtf %>% group_by(name) %>% summarize_all( ~ list(.[!is.na(.)]))

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#     name      res1      res2      res3
#   <fctr>    <list>    <list>    <list>
# 1    bar <dbl [1]> <int [1]> <dbl [1]>
# 2    foo <dbl [2]> <int [1]> <dbl [3]>
```

the data:

```
dtf <- read.table(textConnection('name res1 res2 res3
foo   1.1   NA   10
foo   2.4   NA  2.1
foo   NA     1  1.2
bar     1    2    3'), header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks (+1). I struggled for a few hours on extracting statistics from the tibble, and just went with the "long" version instead. However, you answered the question as posed, so I'll accept!

Answer (score 0):

I took me a few hours, but I worked out a strategy based on thelatemail's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029780/how-can-i-nest-my-data-frame-based-on-identical-values-in-a-column#comment79019607_46029780) of creating a long version.

Input the data (thanks mt1022 for the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029872/1944384)).

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection('
name res1 res2 res3
foo   1.1   NA   10
foo   2.4   NA  2.1
foo   NA     1  1.2
bar     1    2    3'), header = TRUE)
```

Create the long version, as per the comment:

```
long <- cbind(dat["name"], stack(dat[-1]))
```

As per [here](https://martinsbioblogg.wordpress.com/2014/03/25/using-r-quickly-calculating-summary-statistics-from-a-data-frame/), use ddply to output statistics.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(long, c("name","ind"), summarise,
  count = length(values[!is.na(values)]),
  mean = mean(values[!is.na(values)]),
  sd = sd(values[!is.na(values)]),
  sem = sd(values[!is.na(values)])/sqrt(length(values[!is.na(values)])))
```

Answer (score 0):

`tidyverse` provides this functionality with `nest` and `map`

#### your data

```
mydf <- structure(list(name = c("foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"), res1 = c(1.1, 
2.4, NA, 1), res2 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L), res3 = c(10, 2.1, 1.2, 
3)), .Names = c("name", "res1", "res2", "res3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

#### tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
# nest 'other'-columns by `name` group
nesteddf <- mydf %>%
          group_by(name) %>%
          nest()

#    name             data
#   <chr>           <list>
# 1   foo <tibble [3 x 3]>
# 2   bar <tibble [1 x 3]>  

# perform operations on nested data with `mutate(data = map(data, ~...)`
stats <- nesteddf %>%
           mutate(data = map(data, ~mean(.x$res3, na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
           unnest(data)

#    name     data
#   <chr>    <dbl>
# 1   foo 4.433333
# 2   bar 3.000000
```